# Delphi как сделать прозрачный фон для Gif

Tags: delphi

Сделал гиф анимацию загрузки на форме. Но возле гифки белый фон, как сделать его цвета формы. Пробывал убрать фон у гифки, но тогда получаются ужасно не красивые пиксели.

Comment: Приведите код, как вы добавили GIF, напишите какие компоненты использовали.

Answer (score 1):

*Комментарии не могу пока оставлять.*

Фон в gif делать под цвет формы нельзя, потому что в Windows цвет формы может меняться в зависимости от настроек пользователя (выбранной темы).

Нужно смотреть в сторону [apng](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) (Animated Portable Network Graphics) он поддерживает нормальный альфа канал для прозрачности.

Comment: В вопросе фигурирует анимация. Как вы предлагаете делать анимацию в PNG?

Comment: По таймеру менять заранее загруженную картинку (или выдирать из большой картинки часть и копировать в нужное место формы). А еще есть apng.

Comment: Не нужно изобретать велосипед с таймерами и "выдиранием", лучше использовать apng.

Answer (score 0):

Нужна гифка с прозрачностью. Примеры: https://www.google.com/search?q=loading+gif&tbm=isch&tbs=ic:trans

Стандартный `TImage` в Delphi 2010 поддерживает прозрачность. Насчет более ранних версий не в курсе.

Answer (score -1):

Если форма за gif-изображением однотонная то лучше всего у гифки просто залить фон цветом формы. Лучше в таком случаи иметь исходник анимации например в psd или векторе. Иначе залить так чтобы выглядело хорошо может не получится, особенно если разрешение картинки с анимацией небольшое.